# Javascript array collection append

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

Hi so i got this array:

```
  var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1] 
];
```

and i want to append to it just like it is example:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1],
  ['New item', -22.950198, 141.259302, 6]
];
```

I have no idea how to do it, search 'Add items to array in array ' didn't quite seem to work out.

Comment: Array.prototype.push

Comment: `locations.push(['New item', -22.950198, 141.259302, 6]);`

Comment: Your last comment isn't correct. You are not adding items to array in array. You are simply adding to an array. You can `push` any item it just so happens this item is an array. But if you wanted to add items to an array inside an array you would locate the array to add to and `push` as well. So would be like: `locations[1].push(whatever)`. This would push whatever to the end of the 'Coogee Beach' array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1] 
];

var newLocation = ['New item', -22.950198, 141.259302, 6];

locations.push(newLocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

locations.push( ['New item', -22.950198, 141.259302, 6]);
ist the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use push() method if you want to add on the last !
or you can add in the first by using .unshift method ! look here for more informations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
 var locations = [
 {'Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4},
 {'Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5},
 {'Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3},
 {'Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2},
 {'Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1}
```

];

Now you can apply a push

```
locations.push({'New item', -22.950198, 141.259302, 6});
```

Let me know if it work.

Comment: You are pushing an object; not array.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1] 
];

locations = [...locations,['New item', -22.950198, 141.259302, 6]];

console.log(locations);
```